# print variable to text area instead of console in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text

little confused on this. I currently have some variables printing to my console when a button is pressed, but instead I'd like for them to print to a text area (on a single line) instead.

Here's my code

```js
const freq = palindromes.map(palindrome => ({
  palindrome,
  freq: frequency(palindrome)
}));
console.log('all sentences:', sentences);
console.log('only palindromes:', palindromes);
console.log(freq);
```

```html
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Which just in the console shows-

```
[{
  freq: {
   a: 2,
   c: 2,
   e: 1,
   r: 2
},
  palindrome: "racecar"
}]
```

Instead of this I want it to display like `[{freq: { a: 2, c: 2, e: 1,r: 2}, palindrome: "racecar"}]` inside the text area I defined in the html. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the array to a string, then assign it to the value of the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('output').value = JSON.stringify('your variable')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement what you are trying to do assuming I am interpreting your question correctly. It sounds like you want a text field, or in this case through the use of the textarea tag, to hold some string of characters rather then being empty? This can be done once at start up or dynamically through a button or something during run time. The code needed looks something like this:

```
<textarea id="output">
default text.
</textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="upDateOutput()">Click to update text area</button>

<script>
function upDateOutput() {
  document.getElementById("output").value = "This is a new string.";
}
</script>
```